# Toggle all GIFs on a page with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, gif

For accessibility reasons, I want to use a button to stop all GIFs on a HTML page from moving. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: See also: https://github.com/juliemoynat/stop-gifs/blob/main/stop-gifs-bookmarklet.md ; also, I'd note that folks who have accessibility issues with animation will likely have disabled them [at the browser level already](https://www.pcmag.com/how-to/how-to-stop-gifs-from-auto-playing-in-your-browser).